# grep with python to match string inside quotes in html files

Tags: python, html, grep

I am newbie in grep and I'm familiar with Python. My problem is to find and replace every string inside the quote like "text" by < em >text< /em >

The source file has the html form

Thanks

Comment: I understand the problem. I have no idea why your attempted solution doesn't work, because you haven't posted it. I can't help you fix it if you don't show it to me

Comment: Why are you trying to combine grep with Python? If you're familiar with Python, why not just use the built-in String/RegEx libraries?

Comment: Yes I mean using python and the regrex library in python... Yes I did not try hard to find the solution because I think It's easy and recurrent problem that lots of people know the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That'll do the trick

```
import re

s = '"text" "some"'
res = re.subn('"([^"]*)"', '<em>\\1</em>', s)[0]
```